# Need help specifying a ending while condition

Tags: python, while-loop, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I have written a Python script to download all of the [xkcd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xkcd) comic images. The only problem is I can't tell it to stop when it gets to the last one... Here is what I have so far.

```
import re, mechanize
from urllib import urlretrieve
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as bs

baseUrl = "http://xkcd.com/1/" #Specify the first comic page
br = mechanize.Browser() #Create a browser

response = br.open(baseUrl) #Create an initial response

x = 1 #Assign an initial file name
while (SomeCondition):
    soup = bs(response.get_data()) #Create an instance of bs that contains the response data
    img = soup.findAll('img')[1] #Get the online file path of the image
    localFile = "C:\\Comics\\xkcd\\" + str(x) + ".jpg"  #Come up with a local file name
    urlretrieve(img["src"], localFile) #Download the image file
    response = br.follow_link(text = "Next >") #Store the response of the next button
    x += 1 #Increase x by 1
print "All xkcd comics downloaded" #Let the user know the images have been downloaded
```

Initially what I had was something like

```
while br.follow_link(text = "Next >") != br.follow_link(text = ">|"):
```

but by doing this I actually send skip to the last page before the script has a chance to perform the intended purpose.

Comment: erm, or you could use [interface for automated systems to access comics and metadata](http://xkcd.com/about/)...

Comment: @ rebus Yea, but I want to reuse it for other online comics, not all of which have that nice .json system. I simply chose xkcd as the comic to test the script on because it doesn't have a bunch of adds and stuff floating around. @Soumya92 there are no buttons on the last page that return a 404.

Comment: Just go through 1.png, 2.png, 3.png, ... Of course, this only works for XKCD. For others, you could check to see if the latest links to the current, or if the next button is present at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you follow the "Next" link from the most recent xkcd comic, a hash tag is appended to the URL. Try using the following.

```
while not br.geturl().endswith("#"):
    ...
```

Comment: Yep that is what I was looking for. I was working on a similar solution, that wasn't working. I'll spare you the bad code.